# PHP/MySQL - Next/Previous buttons based on date/time with dupliate date/times

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Let's say I have a calendar with items on it, When you click on one of them I want to provide a next/previous button. For example:

```
ID      Time    Name
123     8:30    Apple
432     9:00    1 Plumb
43      9:00    2:2 Kale
663     9:00    Apples
12      9:00    Berry
235     9:00    Carrot
62      11:00   Tomato
23      11:30   Pepper
```

Listing these on the calendar is easy enough:

```
SELECT *
FROM fruits
WHERE date="2020-09-30"
ORDER BY 
    STR_TO_DATE(`time`, '%H:%i') ASC,
    name ASC;
```

The problem I'm having is getting an accurate next/previous item, and it only is a problem when all items start at the same time, for instance 9:00 am:

```
# Previous Button - Should get Apples, but it returns `Carrots`
SELECT 
    name
FROM fruits 
WHERE 
    id != '12' #Berry
AND TIMESTAMP(date, time) <= TIMESTAMP('2020-09-30', '9:00') 
ORDER BY 
    date DESC, 
    STR_TO_DATE(time, '%H:%i') DESC, 
    name DESC
LIMIT 1;

# Next Button - Should get Carrot, but it returns `1 Plumb`
SELECT 
    name
FROM fruits 
WHERE 
    id != '12' #Berry
AND TIMESTAMP(date, time) >= TIMESTAMP('2020-09-30', '9:00') 
ORDER BY 
    date ASC, 
    STR_TO_DATE(time, '%H:%i') ASC, 
    name ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

I understand why, but I don't know how to fix it.

If I could filter alpha-numerically, like REGEX '^[A-p-a-p1-0]', but then I have to do tonnes of PHP to figure out if it's numeric or alpha, and then juggle variables that would quickly get confusing. Plus I'd need to probably loop the array which is even messier.

I could use a variable, and number the rows dynamically, but then I also need to use PHP to figure out where in the loop I am, and find the next one, and I'd need to fetch dozens of rows to ensure I don't miss one.

To be clear - this table has millions of rows, the data changes often, and mulitple people can change the data at anytime, so I need something fast and dynamic.

I've created a DB Fiddle with all the data and queries above to make any help easier to provide:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a5qnbhUgcG9j9irkzawKHx/0

Any ideas?

**UPDATE :: Solution as per Nicks answer**

See his answer for a full explanation. His answer is more dynamic and doesn't require PHP, I wanted to bypass subqueries so I ended up using a tiny bit of PHP. Thank you very much, I never would have solved this in a single query without your help!

PHP:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($date.' '.$time);
```

MySQL

```
# Previous
SELECT 
    name
FROM fruits 
WHERE 
    (
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(`date`, `time`)) - $timestamp < 0
           OR 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(`date`, `time`)) - $timestamp = 0 
        AND name < '$name'
    )
ORDER BY 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(`date`, `time`)) - $timestamp DESC, 
    name DESC
LIMIT 1;

# Next
SELECT 
    name
FROM fruits 
WHERE 
    (
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(`date`, `time`)) - $timestamp > 0
           OR 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(`date`, `time`)) - $timestamp = 0 
        AND name > '$name'
    )
ORDER BY 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(`date`, `time`)) - $timestamp ASC, 
    name ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: since you will be making the decision of what the order is, what if you read it into something iterable beforehand like a stack or list?

Comment: I thought of this, the problem is this table has millions of rows, changes often, and the same data can be shown in slighly different collections used by multiple people at the same time, so as far as I know there's no fesabile way of pre-determining an order, it has to be dynamic. However, if altering the original order might solve the problem I'm open to that as a solution. Either way, an example would be appreciated using my fiddle.

Comment: are you refreshing the table then? I would create the arrays when you do that. If not then upon click, but that is a lot of back and forth to the server idk.

Comment: Each time the calendar of items is displayed, yes it's just fetching the data. I have some really fast indexes setup. I don't think I could create an array, because technically you could click on the first item in "September", and then you need a previous button for the last item in "August", so the array would have to be hundreds of items long, and even then it's possible you might find yourself in a situation where it's outside the bounds of what you accounted for.

Comment: Why should `Carrot` be after `Berry`? it's at the same time...

Comment: Because when it's listed in the Calendar, it's easily sorted by `Name ASC`, but when you click into Berry, the previous/next should be what you saw listed on the Calendar (`previous Apples`, `next Carrots`), but I can't figure out how to filter that way dynamically, or if it's even possible. So instead I'm stuck with `previous Carrots`, `next 1 Plumbs`, and now those buttons become either a never ending loop around the items at 9:00am, or it misses several items entirely, thus making them broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the results you want by computing the difference between the timestamp of each entry and the timestamp of `id = 12` (Berry), and selecting either those rows where the difference is `<= 0` and `name < 'Berry'` for the previous row or rows where the difference is `>= 0` and `name > 'Berry'` for the next row. For example, for the previous row:

```
SELECT name AS previous,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i')) -
    (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i')) 
     FROM fruits 
     WHERE id = 432) AS tsdiff
FROM fruits
HAVING tsdiff < 0 OR tsdiff = 0 AND name < (SELECT name FROM fruits WHERE id = 432)
ORDER BY tsdiff DESC, name DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
previous    tsdiff
Apple 4     -84600
```

Note I've used a `HAVING` clause to allow me to to use an alias. This may not perform as well as using a `WHERE` clause, however that will require duplicating the timestamp calculation:

```
SELECT 
    name AS previous
FROM fruits 
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i')) -
    (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i')) 
     FROM fruits 
     WHERE id = 432) < 0
     OR UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i')) -
    (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i')) 
     FROM fruits 
     WHERE id = 432) = 0 AND name < (SELECT name FROM fruits WHERE id = 432)
ORDER BY 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i')) -
    (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i')) 
     FROM fruits 
     WHERE id = 432) DESC,
    name DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Demo of both queries on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5LaFmC15SuizALfEMrucXn/3).

Note also that you should store your `time` values in a `TIME` column, or at least a column formatted as `%H:%i` to ensure `TIMESTAMP` works as expected. To work around that I've used `STR_TO_DATE`, if the data was stored correctly you could use

```
TIMESTAMP(date, time)
```

where I have used

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i')
```

Comment: Wow, that's an incredibly creative solution, thank you. Unforuntely it only seems to work when everything is at the same time, like 9:00. As soon as you start changing dates and times, it starts to fail. For example selecting ID #432: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5LaFmC15SuizALfEMrucXn/0

Comment: @Maurice apologies, my condition was wrong. I've corrected the query and updated the demo link. Note that in your demo in the comment you have the ordering in the next query wrong, they should both be ASC, not DESC. See my demo.

Comment: I could kiss you. You wouldn't even believe how much time I've spent trying different solutions. I managed to find a much cleaner solution with a tiny bit of PHP, I will post this shortly for anyone who stumbles across this in the future.

Comment: My pleasure, all done, I tried to make it as simple and obvious as possible.

Comment: @Maurice you shouldn't need these tests as they are implied by the next two: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(`date`, `time`)) >= $timestamp`

Comment: Good call, even simpler :)